# Parsing Twitter search results in JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, api

I'm able to pull out information from the user_timeline with:

```
$recentTweets = $connection->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=username&count=1');
for ($i=0; $i<count($recentTweets); $i++){
    echo $recentTweets[$i]->text;
};
```

But it doesn't seem to work with Twitter's search results. I assume it has to do with the fact it is formatted differently? I'm seeing 'stdClass Object' when I use print_r, which I don't see with the results from the user_timeline.

```
$cowTweets = $connection->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/search.json?q=cow&count=1');
for ($i=0; $i<count($cowTweets); $i++){
    echo $cowTweets[$i]->text;
};
```

I'm using Abraham's TwitterOauth library if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just use something like this and iterate through the assoc array you get from it:

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=username&count=1'),true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$cowTweets = $connection->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/search.json?q=cow&count=1');
```

Try this because it is a JSON response:
case your `count=1` use:

```
echo $cowTweets->statuses[0]->text;
```

case `count > 1` use

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $cowTweets->statuses ); $i++ ) {
    echo $cowTweets->statuses[ $i ]->text;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find you're answer here : [PHP Twitter Hashtag Search showing no results in parse but data present in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038526/php-twitter-hashtag-search-showing-no-results-in-parse-but-data-present-in-array)

hope it's help !